# Is it possible to create multiple data source objects under the same database executing a single xmla script?

Tags: ssas

I want to create multiple data source objects under the same database executing the single XMLA script only once.I have tried the below script but it did not work.If I define only a single  node, the script executes successfully.But when I add the another same node it gives error. I am newer to this.Please guide.

```
<Create xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
    <ParentObject>
        <DatabaseID>Test Database</DatabaseID>
    </ParentObject>
    <ObjectDefinition>
            <DataSource xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="RelationalDataSource">
                <ID>Test Datasource1</ID>
                <Name>Test Datasource1</Name>
                <Description>A test datasource1.</Description>
                <ConnectionString>Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=servername;User ID=user;Password=pass;Initial Catalog=SqlDb</ConnectionString>
                <ImpersonationInfo>
                    <ImpersonationMode>ImpersonateServiceAccount</ImpersonationMode>
                </ImpersonationInfo>
                <Timeout>PT0S</Timeout>
            </DataSource>
        <DataSource xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="RelationalDataSource">
            <ID>Test Datasource2</ID>
            <Name>Test Datasource2</Name>
            <Description>A test datasource2.</Description>
            <ConnectionString>Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=servername;User ID=user;Password=pass;Initial Catalog=SqlDb</ConnectionString>
            <ImpersonationInfo>
                <ImpersonationMode>ImpersonateServiceAccount</ImpersonationMode>
            </ImpersonationInfo>
            <Timeout>PT0S</Timeout>
        </DataSource>
    </ObjectDefinition>
</Create>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a batch element wrapper you can use?